VS Code keeps reopening closed file
I'm noticing behavior where VS Code keeps re-opening and focusing a file in the main editor pane after I take some action away from the main editor pane (run a command in terminal, adjust sidebar panes, among others).
The behavior occurs randomly but frequently and is making the editor nigh-on-unusable.  I've tried disabling SCM working sets and most of my extensions to no avail.

What's the question? If you want to file a bug report, that's on the VSCode repo. Otherwise, check out How to ask a good question and [edit] to clarify.


What file is this? 2) Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command (run in the command palette) into your question post. 3) Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled command in the command palette)? If not, then do an extension bisect to figure out what extension is causing it.

